# Why jQuery .addClass() could be beneficial than modify HTML directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am really green to jQuery and when come across these two methods, I do not know why it is useful.

```
.addClass() and .removeClass()
```

Yes, I can add the class in my `js` file. But why would it be beneficial? Is it because we are not suppose to modify the HTML?

The case I have:

In HTML:

```
 <div id="title" class="highlighted">I'm highlighted!</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.highlighted {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

If I want to add `.highlighted` to any `div` in my HTML, I can simply add it like this:

```
<div id="text" class='highlighted'>Highlight me, too!</div>
```

Why do I need to bother do this in my `js` file?

```
 $('#text').addClass('highlighted');
```

Comment: `addClass` and `removeClass` are meant for *dynamically* changing the `classList` (upon some event, for example), after the page has already been loaded and the HTML already received from the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you might want to add the Class when something else happens, maybe when clicking on the div.

```
$("#text").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlighted')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addClass()/removeClass()` methods come in handy when you are trying to dynamically add/remove a class that an element might not originally have.

This comes in handy when let's say you select an element and you want to add a highlighted class to convey a selection. It's a great tool to use when you want to change things around when you have good user interaction so you can return immediate feedback to a user given their choices.

Answer (score 0):

You would use addClass and removeClass for dynamically created elements, animation effects, or as the result of an event.

**Dynamically created elements:** 
 Example, if you click a button that creates a div on your page. Perhaps later you need to apply a class to the div.

**Animation effects:**
You can use addClass to animate position and colors of elements. One example on the top of my head is parallax scrolling websites, where when you reach a certain location, an effect is applied. In addition, removeClass could then be called when scrolling back up to reverse the effect.

**Result of an event:**
Adding a click event to a button that adds a class to change an elements color, font size, etc.